# Is it less 'expensive' to pass the field of an object as opposed to the whole object itself?

Tags: c#, methods, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Consider the following class:

```
public class Person
{
    public String FirstName;
    public String LastName;
    public DateTime DateOfBirth;
    public StaffType PersonType;
}
```

And the following 2 methods and method calls:

```
public void DoSomethingWithPersonType(Person person)
{
    TestMethod(person.PersonType);
}
```

(called by `DoSomethingWithPersonType(person);`)

```
public void DoSomethingWithPersonType(StaffType personType)
{
    TestMethod(personType)
}
```

(called by `DoSomethingPersonType(person.PersonType);`).

Which method is more efficient? Are they both as 'efficient' as each other? Does it make no difference because it's only one reference passed in anyway? Or does the reference passed differ in some way?

The reason I ask is because I've opted for the first method signature in a current project - and I've done it because at a later date we may need to use other fields of our 'person' - so a more easily scalable/adaptable method is what I've got - but is it a more expensive one?

EDIT: Note - it goes without saying that these differences will be marginal, otherwise I would've already encountered scenarios were the performance implications are evident enough for me to act on. It's simply a matter of curiosity.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by more "expensive"?

Comment: In the first method, you're dealing with two references rather than one, so it would probably be more expensive... although really the cases where it'll make any difference at all are probably very rare.

Comment: Discussing efficiency instead of expense would maybe have been a bit of a better choice of wording I suppose.

Comment: @Sconibulus - thanks a lot. I understand it's very rarely going to make a substantial enough difference to worry about - was just curious.

Answer (score 8):

Performance wise they will be identical.  In both cases you are passing a single reference (which has the same performance cost) and in both cases you're getting the `PersonType` object out of one of the fields.

The only difference here is in terms of code readability/maintainability, etc.  In general, it's best for methods to only accept what information they need.  If you only need a `PersonType` then only accept a `PersonType`.  It allows that method to be used more flexibly.  (What if something other than a `Person` has a `PersonType`?)  If you think you'll actually need more than just the person type than accepting a `Person` may be appropriate.

Also note that even if there is a difference here, it would most certainly be tiny.  You shouldn't think about every little think in terms of how expensive it is to run.  Computers are fast these days.  Even poor algorithms tend to take little time to run in practice (from the point of view of a person).  If you get to the point where your program is taking longer to run than it needs to, then it's time to start looking for places to improve.  You should focus on those areas of the code (identified with a profiler) as being a significant percentage of the processor time.  Network communication (including database calls), and other IO tend to be good targets for optimizations.

Also note that it's generally considered bad practice to have public fields.  At the very least, you should probably have public properties instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Servy - just the answer I was after. This is certainly not concerns me at all, nothing I will be wasting time on - simply a case of curiosity. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - the OP was really quickly thrown together, I very rarely define fields without a relevant Get Set anyway.

Comment: I disagree that passing and enum and an object reference will be literally identical in performance. An object reference creates GC work and also, they will typically be different sizes.

Comment: @Dughall As I have said in response to your answer, no, there will be no GC work as a result of passing an object reference.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you decide to pass to the method performance implications will depend on context. If you pass parameters between methods in the same class performance implication will be immeasurably small, if you call a method over RMI it is a different matter

Answer (score 2):

That depends somewhat on the type of `StaffType`, but normally the performance difference is negligible.

If `StaffType` if a class, then there isn't any difference, as both are references. If it's an `enum` then it would be marginally faster to pass a `StaffType` value than a reference.

(If `StaffType` is a large `struct`, then it would be slower to pass, but then the actual problem is a badly designed `struct`, not how you use it.)

So, you should use the one that makes most sense. Usually you should send as little information as possible, just to make it easier to see what the method actually uses. Whether you should send the `StaffType` value or the entire `Person` object for future possible expansion is hard to tell, but consider the [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) principle - You Ain't Gonna Need It.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, StaffType is an enum. In this case, it should be marginally more efficient than passing an object reference, the enum will create less work for garbage collection.

But any difference will be negligible, I would rate extensibility as far more important in this case.

Comment: Garbage collection?  Nothing is allocated on the heap in either case here.  Passing a reference to an already allocated object doesn't involve any GC work.  In any case, these are parameters, they are on the stack, so the GC isn't involved in allocating/deallocating those items.  Taking up a few extra bytes on the stack is pretty tiny, and will have no runtime speed implications.

Comment: As I said, any difference will be negligible. It's not necessarily true at all that passing a reference to a heap object doesn't involve GC work. The GC has to track/count references. Nor is it true that a few extra bytes on the stack has no runtime speed implications - try passing a large data structure on the stack to highly recursive method. The data structure size not only makes a speed difference but could take you over the stack allocation limit.

Comment: No, the GC does *not* track/count references; that's not how it works.  Perhaps you should spend a bit of time reading up on the .NET GC.  As for stack allocations, "allocating" more space on the stack is simply incrementing a pointer (the stack pointer).  Incrementing it by 4 words is no more or less expensive than incrementing it by 2 words.  Likewise de-allocating the memory from the stack has no more or less cost, decrimenting the stack pointer by 4 words has the same cost as decrimenting it by 2 words.  The time would only differ in what it takes to copy *useful* data, not in allocating.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of efficiency, they are equal becuase in both cases you'll pass a reference (speaking of two classes, else if `StaffType` is a struct the second one will be slower). But in terms of *Best Coding Practices*, it depends on what do you want to do. If you don't need any other property from the `Person` class you should use the second one, because you should pass less information as possible, but if you have to work more on the person object, you should use the first solution.

But you have to think to the *re-usability* of the method and your framework, let's say you need to use this method not only for the *Person type* but you also need it for another "type" you'll have to rewrite another method for it, and the aim of *object oriented programming*, which is code less, will disappear.